# Multi-Classing: Listing Two(or more) Lines Of Work On Careers?

Tags: discussion, jobs, cv

Is anyone with professional experience outside of software development listing their other lines of work? I plan to list my CV on Careers, but I can't decide whether to only list IT and programming experience, or if I should list qualifications of my other career as well. Which is not to say that they are completely separate, as there has been some overlap.

The way I see it, my other career stuff is relevant, and may be *extremely* relevant to a small niche... but to others, the majority, it is just going to look like nonsense and lower the signal-to-noise ratio.

Keep it simple or go all out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't put it on your public CV. But on the private CV side it might be ok -- maybe post it as abbreviated versions so potential employers can scan it quickly, and you can elaborate if they ask? That would be a good compromise.